# Converting complex table layout using div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to migrate a table layout to a more modern div layout but get lost on how to do this. What I'm trying to do is get the following layout working:

```
    ---------------       ----------
    |      A      |       |    B   |
    |             |       |        |
    ---------------       ----------
------------------------------------
|C |      D       |   E   |    F   |
------------------------------------
    ---------------       ----------
    |      G      |       |    H   |
    |             |       |        |
    ---------------       ----------
```

Every width is dependent on each other that is if the content of D grows so does A and G. What I have been trying so far is creating A-H div's and then enclosing them all in a 900px wide div called "content". Then I use position:relative and try to get things correct but this fails since "content" seems not to scale when I use relative positioning. Any suggestions on how to approach a layout like this?

This is the code I have so far:

```css
.content {
  width:1000;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.quad-box{
  float:left;
  margin-left:100px;
  width:400px;
  clear:both;
}

.tl{
  float:left;              
}

null.left-fig{
  text-align:center;
  clear:both;
  width:100px;
}

.oa-ga {
  width:400px;
}

.right-fig{
  text-align:center;
  width:100px;
}

.infield {
  width:400px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.2em;
  color:#999;
  padding:15px 0;
}

ul.events {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

ul.events li {
  -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
  -moz-border-radius:11px;
  border-radius:11px;
  background:#eee;
  color: #707070;
  font-size:1.0em;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  padding:3px 0;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}

ul.intervals {
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
}

ul.intervals li {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  color:#999;
  float:left;
  font-size:1.2em;
  margin:0;
  padding:15px 0;
  text-align:center;
  width: 11.11%;
}

ul.intervals li.first {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.intervals li.no-border {
  border-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- MAIN CONTENT START -->
<div class="content">            
    <div class="quad-box">
        <ul class="events">
            <li style="width:88.88%; left: 11.11%">Event Nr 1</li>        
            <li style="width:100%; left: 0%">Event Nr 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="quad-box">B</div>
    <div class="left-fig tl">C</div>
    <div class="oa-ga tl">
        <ul class="intervals">
            <li class="first">-</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li class="no-border">&nbsp</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li class="no-border">&nbsp</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li class="no-border">&nbsp</li>
            <li>-</li>
            <li>-</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right-fig tl">E</div>
    <div class="infield tl">
        F
    </div>
    <div class="quad-box">G</div>
    <div class="quad-box">H</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your using a fixed width layout. Try using percentages for the div widths:

```
width: 20%;
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/HHfQY/

A better solution would be to use a responsive grid system such as http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/ so you don't have to do all the calculating.

Comment: Nice got me starting but did not result in what i was after, updated the question with code link if you would like to see my results.

Comment: The problem im having is how do I get div3-div5 at a second row. In your example you have two rows but when I try this on my code I get all boxes on the same row. How do I layer div tags in rows?

Comment: @user3748315 Since your using floating divs they will automatically go to the next line once they no longer fit in the current row. You can force a new row by using "clear:both;", which clears left and right floating. See updated example http://jsfiddle.net/5R5nj/2/

Comment: Newest code: http://jsfiddle.net/favetelinguis/5R5nj/5/

A,B and G,H gets ontop of each other now?

Comment: @user3748315 The code is getting a bit messy. I you know how many rows your'e going to have you can create a div for each row. See example http://jsfiddle.net/5R5nj/6/